# Gulp.js starts sass task but doesn't finish

Tags: sass, gulp

My gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// plugins
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');

// compile sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('static/css/scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/static/css/main.css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('static/css/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
})

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

When I run `gulp` I get the following output:

```
[gulp] Using gulpfile /var/www/example/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Starting 'watch'...
[gulp] Finished 'watch' after 21 ms
[gulp] Starting 'default'...
[gulp] Finished 'default' after 23 μs
```

Then when I save my `main.scss` file it outputs:

```
[gulp] Starting 'sass'...
```

At which point it just hangs and never finishes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return inside the sass task seemed to break it, updated my gulpfile.js to following to get it working:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

// plugins
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');

// compile sass
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('static/css/scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/static/css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('static/css/scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
})

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: I noticed the same, but removing the return make gulp not know about the stream, ie. this just removes the wait, but the work is not executing anyway

Comment: The opposite of you, I had to put that `return` in my `compile_scss` task and it worked! Before this, my `compile_scss` task was never finishing and was hanging after the first call. Thanks for sharing your experience to give me the idea to solve! :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who has this issue, I managed to fix this by removing circular imports.

For example...

Before:

```
file1.scss
@import 'file2';

file2.scss
@import 'file1';
```

After:

```
file1.scss
<removed import>

file2.scss
@import 'file1';
```

I didn't actually need the circular dependency, I was just copying/pasting dependencies to the tops of all my scss files.Note that if your files actually need to import one another you'd either need to refactor your files in such a way that you avoid circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The reason my sass compilation was not working and the gulp process was hanging and pinging my processor was that I had an old reference in my .scss file but I had removed the file. There was never any output that complained - this was hard to track down - I got lucky.

`@import 'file-that-has-been-removed-but-still-referenced';`