# Gulp starts sass task but doesn't finish. Compiling doesn't work

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I have very strange problem with compiling SCSS file to CSS in Gulp. I work on windows7 64 bit with installed Node v6.9.4, gulp and **gulp-scss** package.

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584962/gulp-js-starts-sass-task-but-doesnt-finish) - but those solutions is not acceptable becouse without return compilation did not happen.

Anyway, my problem is that after command "gulp sass" in console I see only:

```
Using gulpfile...
Starting 'sass'...
```

Without last info: **Finishing 'sass' after X ms**

I have standard gulpfile.js task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./css/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

style.scss is simple test:

```
body {
    color: red;
    p {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

This file won't compile to by using "gulp sass". No errors, no infos are printed or logged (or maybe I dont know where to search logged errors).

Additional informations:

- when I do gulp-watch watcher work properly untill I make change in watched scss file, after change the watcher ends without comiling
- standalone http://koala-app.com/ compile this sass properly
- gulp other commands/packages like gulp-concat, gulp-image-optimization, gulp-concat, gulp-rename or gulp-less **are working properly**
- command "gulp sass" **compile SCSS file properly** when style.scss includes only

  - @font-face definitions
  - mixins and variables definitions
  - for example this code will compile properly:

  @mixin default() {
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
      margin: 0px auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
      p {
          @include default();
      }
  }

**But when I change @include default(); to some CSS definition color: #fff; it wont compile, wont display Finished 'scss'.**

Please help me what is going on?

Comment: does .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))  give any helpful info?

Comment: nothing, any info in console

Comment: Is there a generated CSS file at all - like an empty one - or it just doesn't generate that file?

Comment: any file is not generated